# Numpy iteration and append

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, loops, numpy, iteration

I'm basically trying to loop through the array, substracting the first element from the second, the second from the third and so on and append my result into a new numpy array.

```
t = np.array([0, 10, 15, 35, 40, 24, 50, 90])

for i in np.nditer(t):
    dt = (t[int(i)] - t[int(i+1)]
    print(dt)
    np.append(dt)
```

Comment: please include your desired result.

Comment: substituting? or subtracting?

Comment: Do not use `np.append` like list append.  It isn't the same, despite the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [**`np.diff(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), that each time subtracts an item from the previous one.

For example:

```
>>> np.diff(np.array([0, 10, 15, 35, 40, 24, 50, 90]))
array([ 10,   5,  20,   5, -16,  26,  40])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also **[zip(...)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)** to have your desired output:

```
out = np.array(list(v - k for k, v in zip(t, t[1:])))
# Also you can use:
# np.fromiter((v - k for k, v in zip(t, t[1:])), int) 
# and out value is:
# array([ 10,   5,  20,   5, -16,  26,  40])
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand this

Comment: @IfeanyiAnene `zip` is a python built in function, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: @ChihebNexus I think the OP may be talking about the use of the in-place for loop? I suggested an edit for your answer that might help.

Comment: @Enthus3d it's called list comprehension. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @ChihebNexus ah yes, the name slipped me. I think you should be explaining to how the concept works to the OP rather than me, however.

Comment: @Enthus3d This is not the case of the OP question. If the OP know what np.nditer do and he/she have no idea about list comprehension ... So, i think there is some things he/she needs to know before using numpy or any framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use iteration and np.append like you did in your original code you could do this:

```
t = np.array([0, 10, 15, 35, 40, 24, 50, 90])
dt=np.array([]) #defining an array to store the results in
prev=None #defining a variable to store the value of i in the last iteration in

for i in np.nditer(t): #iterating trough the values of t
    if not prev==None: #checking if this is the first iteration
        a=i-prev
        dt=np.append(arr=dt,values=a) #appending a to dt
    prev=i #set prev to the current i to use it in the next iteration
print(dt) #print the result
```

this is not the most elegant solution,but it may help you to see your mistakes.